# GMap API 3 click trigger link marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

i try to make external link for auto open and zoom the info window from a  but i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: triggerClick is not defined`.

I know its cause of the fact it is not a global function, but, if i put not in initMap(){} my markers will be not know by the  triggerclick function.

I dont know how to do, can you help me ?

Here the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9u2g4ue5/

My triggerclick function :

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initMap);
    function triggerClick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    //map.getBounds();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also declare a global function inside another function.

the `global` scope in javascript is the `window`-object, just assign the function as a property of `window`

```
window.triggerClick = function(i) {
  //........
}
```

Comment: With this, i go no errors, that's nice, but my marker link still doesnt work :/

Comment: there is no `click`-handler for the items of `markers`

Comment: I should add something like this `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) { //something for zoom }` 

?

Comment: Yes, but you must also set `markers[i]` to `marker` (currently the items of `markers` are arrays, not `google.maps.Markers`) https://jsfiddle.net/4q1y113o/